# Cloning Couch DB data from one server to another through file systems (without replicator)

Tags: couchdb

We have two nodes with couchDB installed. One of the nodes have data on it, we want to copy the data from that instance to another instance of couch db. We want to avoid replicator due to volume of the data.
We tried copying data from %couchdb%/data/shards and %couchdb%/data/.shards to corresponding locations of target node as per one of the suggestions from [CouchDB backups and cloning the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121599/couchdb-backups-and-cloning-the-database)
 but not able to see the Data in the server Fauxton UI. Can someone suggest what is missing?

Answer (score -1):

[Couchtransform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/couchtransform) lets you convert or just clone data from one db to another, its multi threaded and won't need to deal with massive files.